# New Three20 Build-Error

Tags: objective-c, iphone, three20, xcodebuild

i just upgraded my Project to the newest Three20 Build.
When compiling i get following errors:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "___restore_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) sharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) releaseSharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) allocWithZone:] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
  "___save_vfp_d8_d15_regs", referenced from:
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) sharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) releaseSharedInstance] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
  +[TTEntityTables(TTSingleton) allocWithZone:] in libThree20Core.a(TTEntityTables.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anybody with an idea what happened here?

Thanks in advance,
Lukas

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162336/building-iphone-sdk-2-x-targets-with-base-sdk-3-0-when-linking-static-libraries or http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/ea4e1600516da476